# Header value: make `application/vnd.api+json` mandatory

Tags: python, api

I'm developing a restfull jsonapi in python and implemented a validation through marshmallow.

I'm using a combination of two libraries [SAFRS](https://github.com/thomaxxl/safrs) and [flask-rest-jsonapi](https://flask-rest-jsonapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I add the second library to include a marshmallow validation, as the library SAFRS doesn't have it. I followed this [example](https://github.com/thomaxxl/safrs/blob/master/examples/demo_flaskrestjsonapi.py).

The validation is defined through schemas:

```
class UserSchema(Schema):
    class Meta:
        type_ = 'user'
        self_view = 'user_detail'
        self_view_kwargs = {'id': '<id>'}
        self_view_many = 'user_list'

    id = fields.Integer(as_string=True, dump_only=True)
    user_name = fields.Str(required=True, attribute='username', allow_none=False)
    password = fields.Str(required=True, allow_none=False)
    display_name = fields.Function(lambda obj: "{} <{}>".format(obj.username.upper(), obj.username))
```

I found out, that the validation is only effective if the content-type of the header is `application/vnd.api+json`.
The problem is that requests under the header `application/json`  are also accepted, and in this case, the validation is ignored.

Therefore, is there be a way to make `application/vnd.api+json` mandatory?

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal example?

Comment: @James I added more information, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Found different ways of fixing the problem. One way would be via middleware, but the error handling there is not optimal. At the end I chose this one:

```
    app = Flask("my_app")
    @app.before_request
    def header_check():
        if request.content_type != 'application/vnd.api+json':
            data = {
                "errors": [
                    {
                        "detail": "Content-Type header must be application/vnd.api+json",
                        "title": "Invalid request header",
                        "status": "415"
                    }
                ]
            }
            response = app.response_class(response=json.dumps(data),
                                          status=415,
                                          mimetype='application/json')
            return response
```